# If M is a transition matrix, 1 is one of its eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ Markov, Transition or Stochastic matrix (i.e. $A_{ij} \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij}=1$) one of its eigenvalues is equal to 1?

Comment: An eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ would correspond to a stable state. Intuitively, such a thing should always exist. The proof itself is probably to prove your question, though, and that is done very well below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same eigenvalues, and $A^\top \cdot \vec 1 =\vec 1$, because all row sums of $A^\top$ are equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks so much! How is it that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: $\det(A^\top - \lambda I) = \det((A - \lambda I)^\top) = \det(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: @JonathanGinsburg They have the same characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 0):

$A-I$ is not full rank as all of the rows have sum equal to $0$, and thus do not span all of $\mathbb R^n$, we conclude $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.